# SQL Server advanced sorting out

Tags: sql, sql-server, razor

I am an asp.net web pages developer I am developing a website in which I need advanced sorting like [www.olx.com](http://olx.in/cameras/?view=galleryWide) which is a classifieds website but the problem is that I have more than 25 categories I am using SQL Server & have my tables broken into parts.

Now, as I have many categories so when i sort them for example if I search for samsung but at the same time I want to sort search data by price (high to low or low to high) & also at same time I want to filter data which has a description now I would need to make 100's of queries by using if's but is there a more convenient solution to this problem

Currently I am using this query:

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM users_table INNER JOIN response_table ON users_table.ID = response_table.ID LEFT OUTER JOIN miscellaneous_table ON users_table.ID = miscellaneous_table.ID LEFT OUTER JOIN response_table2 ON users_table.ID = response_table2.ID";

sql = sql + " where response_table.sub_category='" + incat + "'";

if (Request["search"] != "" && Request["search"] != null)
{
    var search = Request["search"].Trim();
    string[] querynew = search.Split(' ');
    var searchquery = " and ";

    foreach (string word in querynew)
    {
        searchquery += " users_table.adtitle LIKE '%" + word + "%' OR ";
    }

    sql = sql + searchquery.Remove(searchquery.Length - 4);
}

if (Request["min"] != "" && Request["min"] != null && Request["max"] != null && Request["max"] != "")
{
    sql = sql + " and (CAST(response_table.price AS Float)) between " + Request["min"].Trim() + " AND " + Request["max"].Trim();
}
```

Thanks

Comment: What's your DBMS? SQL Server?

Comment: yes i am using sql server

Comment: Argh! The sql injection vulnerability! It burns us!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this short hand in the WHERE clause

Assuming your filter are @col1, @col2, @col3

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE (@col1 = 0 OR col1 = @col1)
AND (@col2 = '' OR col2 = @col2)
AND (@col3 = 0 OR col3 = @col3)
```

So with the above where clause, if the user only supply filter for col2 then just pass 0 in for col1 & col2 and it will unfilter these.

Comment: No, I Found a much better solution